# How to achieve desired output with background black and segmented line between two text android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

i have listview, above listview i need to place textview with segmented line to place another textview and image exactly to that of expected output, How to achieve this?

```
 Here is code

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    layout="@layout/main_header" />
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sort_filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sorts_holder"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sorts_holder"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sorts_holder"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Events"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sorts_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/filter_holder"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
         android:onClick="Onclick"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_sort"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sort_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sort"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sort By Name"
            android:textColor="@color/sub_textcolor"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sorts_holder"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:onClick="OnClick"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sort By"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/eventslist"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/sort_filter" >
 </ListView>
```

Achieved output is:

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

Expected output is

```
![enter image description here][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

What i understand you question is you want to draw a segmented line. below is the xml code. This draw a thin horizontal line.

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

If i understand your question wrong, Please comment.